# how to design bool query in restful

Tags: rest, go, boolean

I have an user model like this:

```golang
type User struct {
    Name    string
    Enabled bool  // this is an bool field
    Online  bool  // this is an bool field

    // other field ...
}
```

when create user:

```
POST /api/v1/users 
{
    "name": "hello",
    "enabled": true  // option, default is true
}
```

the create request model is:

```golang
type CreateUserReq struct {
    Name    string
    Enabled bool  // but golang default value is false
}
```

when list user:

```
GET /api/v1/users               // list all users, but golang default value is false
GET /api/v1/users?enabled=true  // list enabled users
GET /api/v1/users?enabled=false // list disabled users
```

the list request model is:

```golang
type ListUserReq struct {
    Status bool // but golang default value is false
}
```

What is the common way to solve this problem?

Comment: The default value for booleans is false in pretty much every language, so this may be a problem for many of your clients. Consider renaming the field to "disabled". If you don't want to do that, use a pointer as explained in Eklavya's answer.

Comment: @Peter if renaming to "disabled" the “listAll” Still unnatural

Comment: @Peter if i change the filed type to string, and define "const UserEnabled" and "const UserDisabled", Is this the usual practice?

Comment: No. Using strings for inherently boolean values is a terrible idea. This would make using the API very inconvenient for you and all of your clients. The list endpoint is not a problem, because you have to do string comparisons is any case (all query values are strings).

Answer (score 2):

Variables without an initial value are given their zero value.
For the boolean type zero value is `false`. [Ref](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)

You can use a pointer of `bool` which zero value is `nil`. Then you can check is `Enabled` is set or not. And check in handler if `Enabled` is `nil` then set as `true` for default case.

```
type CreateUserReq struct {
    Name    string
    Enabled *bool  
}
```

Comment: if i change the filed type to string, and define "const UserEnabled" and "const UserDisabled", Is this the usual practice?

Comment: It's not a good practice to use boolean value as string and for string use pointer of string like `*string` if you want to treat  ""(empty string) as differently. I don't think `const ` is ideal for request body